# How to convert X509Certificate's PublicKey to a Base64 string and back?

Tags: c#, base64, x509certificate

I got an RSA PublicKey from a x509Certificate. I want to include it in an XmlDocument as an XmlElement.

So I thought i'd convert the key to base64 and then put it in a new XmlText node.
Something along this line:

```
RSA PubKey = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();                
XmlElement pk = doc.CreateElement("PublicKey");
XmlText txt = doc.CreateTextNode(PubKey.......);                
pk.AppendChild(txt);
doc.AppendChild(pk);
```

What do I do at the .......?

Comment: You can store RSA as XML using  `ToXmlString` and `FromXmlString` methods

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: But if you want to use base64 string, you can use `RSA.ExportRSAPublicKey()` and put it in `Convert.ToBase64String`

Comment: It all depends on what format you're wanting. `new RSAKeyValue(pubKey).GetXml()`, pubKey.GetRSAPublicKey() (then ToBase64), pubKey.GetSubjectPublicKeyInfo() (then ToBase64)... something else. Lots of options.